# Is it possible to forward declare a static const int in the same header?

Tags: c, forward-declaration

So same as title: I want to forward declare a integer so I can use it before I define it but the twist is that it needs to happen in the exact same header file.

My code looks like this:

```
//Embedded system header file for pins and UART.

#if peripheral
#define P4_2 18
#define P4_3 17

static const int AUX_UARTRXD = P4_2;    /* Receive  Data (RXD) at P4.2 */
static const int AUX_UARTTXD = P4_3;    /* Transmit Data (TXD) at P4.3 */

#undef P4_2
#undef P4_3
#endif

static const int P4_2 = 18;
static const int P4_3 = 17;
```

I really want to have a symbolic way to initialize `AUX_UARTRXD` but my solution is really ugly.

Moving the declarations is an option but it would mean that the default pattern for the header files would get changed.

Comment: TL;DR: No. This seems like an XY problem: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem Since most R/T UART header files define all the stuff you need, why are you defining one? Why use `static const int` instead of `enum`? Why not just put `P4_2` and `P4_3` in a separate header file (e.g. `p4def.h`) and just include it where needed. This minimizes the include hierarchy mess. But, if it's really disruptive, I'd wonder about the hierarchy itself. When I've had a similar issue, my solution was to split/reorganize the `.h` files to eliminate `#include` "cycles"

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica whoops didn't retype properly. Will edit  to make sure it at least compiles.

Comment: @CraigEstey I'm using [energia](https://energia.nu/) (arduino for MSP430) and need to roll my own board support for the board I've developed. As such I'm creating a variant in the structure prepared by energia and adding more header files will only create problems down the line. There are several things I would've like to do differently but fitting in with other boards means doing stuff this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is not optimal in your solution is that you have to define twice the values `17` and `18`. It would be a pain in case you have to modify it, introducing a *misalignment risk*.

It's not exactly the forward declaration you are asking for, but it could be even a cleaner solution. What if you add two more defines for the values?

```
// Outside #if peripheral
#define P4_2_VAL 18
#define P4_3_VAL 17

#if peripheral
static const int AUX_UARTRXD = P4_2_VAL;    /* Receive  Data (RXD) at P4.2 */
static const int AUX_UARTTXD = P4_3_VAL;    /* Transmit Data (TXD) at P4.3 */
#endif

static const int P4_2 = P4_2_VAL;
static const int P4_3 = P4_3_VAL;
```

In this way you also get rid of those `#undef`s.

Comment: @dbush Thanks for your precious edit. In my defence I'm answering from my phone.

Comment: That misalignment risk is indeed the reason why I find this "solution" ugly and want to do something different. I guess that defining a separate value beforehand is the best option as it at least keeps these two parameters in sync and gives semantic meaning to the code.